# Is there any way to get a 2d map of the room with the Vive system?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, htc-vive

I want to render a 2d map of the room with a position of all tracked objects on it, but I'm very new to Unity and VR.

I can't really find a way to get the room layout, but I know how to get the position of the objects relative to the room layout already. Can someone guide me to some document or demo code?

Tank you.